# How can save array params using the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

My controller is not saving correctly array params.

Database

```
|categories|
 |id| |name|
   1    HW
   2    SF
   3    PC

|products|
 |id| |amount| |category_id|
```

> But after saving the table 'PRODUCTS', should save array params
>   will be like this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cbwtazar/7/)

```
|products|
 |id| |amount| |category_id|
   1     100          1
   2     200          2
   3     300          3
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @categories = Category.all
  @obj_product = Product.new(params[:obj_product])
end

def create
  params[:obj_product].each do |key , value| 
    o = FlowBudgetDetail.new( :amount => value , :category_id => key)
    o.save
  end

  if o.save()
    redirect_to :action=>"index"
  else
    redirect_to :action=>"new"
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% form_for :obj_product, :url => {:action=>'create'} do |f| %>
   <% @categories.each do |category| %>
     <%= f.text_field :category_id , :name => "obj_product[array_#{category.id}][category_id]"%>
     <%= f.text_field :amount      , :name => "obj_product[array_#{category.id}][amount]" %>
   <% end %>
<$ end %>
```

Log is showing all parameters but is just creating one insert:

```
Processing ProductController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-07 17:23:26) [POST]
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save", "obj_product"=> {"array_1"=>{"amount"=>"100","category_id"=>"1"},"array_2"=>{"amount"=>"300","category_id"=>"2"},"array_3"=>{"amount"=>"300","category_id"=>"3"} }}
INSERT INTO `products` (`category_id`, `amount`) VALUES( 0, 1)
INSERT INTO `products` (`category_id`, `amount`) VALUES( 0, 1)
INSERT INTO `products` (`category_id`, `amount`) VALUES( 0, 1)
```

This should save this:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`category_id`, `amount`) VALUES( 1, 100)
INSERT INTO `products` (`category_id`, `amount`) VALUES( 2, 200)
INSERT INTO `products` (`category_id`, `amount`) VALUES( 3, 300)
```

Is saving incorrect information (incorrect params)

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: You show your `Products` table as having two columns, then it looks like it should have 3 columns after your save? Can you clarify this?

Comment: So you are trying to save three (or more) records at a time?

Comment: Post your web server logs. More than just the one line, particularly the part that shows what params are being passed in by the form. If you are trying to save multiple records into the DB you will have to loop through them in the controller and save each one.

Comment: Also what does your controller params whitelist look like? The `require(...).permit(....` part.

Comment: I see you tagged this as Rails 3.2. In Rails 4 they use a whitelist of parameters rather than `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Wow, that is old. But give my answer a try. Can't promise it will work on Rails 2. If it doesn't I can suggest how you can loop through your params to make it work.

Comment: See my last example. It should allow you to save each of them. The problem is you are trying to do this mass save action but nowhere do you relate `"1"` to the category_id.

Comment: Your last attempt with the transaction is not going to work because you still aren't making it clear to the controller what the "1" , "2", "3" relate to. See my last edit, it shows how to loop through your params and get the info into the object you are creating.

Comment: Note that you are NOT doing it the way I recommended. You are trying to use `create` in the loop instead of `new`. You MUST read this http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class if you are ever going to hope to understand what is going on. `create` make a new object AND saves it. That is why you wrap it into a transaction.  I will expand my answer to make it even more clear.

Comment: I will not put any more time into this unless you  post the code for ALL of the models used in this, I'm tired of guessing at this mess.

Comment: And what controller is this???!!! Products?

Comment: I give up. My latest edit should work except you went and changed your form code so params hash is now completely different. Stop changing so many things when trying to troubleshoot something!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to create multiple records at once but you are trying to do it using a single call to `new` **this is important!!!** In your `Controller#new` action you only ask the DB for ONE object. That's fine I guess to get the form fields you need since you are using your `@categories` to do the number of loops needed. But in your `Controller#create` action you do:

```
 obj_product.new(params[:obj_product])
```

You could try:

```
 obj_product.create(params[:obj_product])
```

But this will NOT work because your params are:

```
"flow_budget_detail"=> {"1"=>{"amount"=>"100"},"2"=>{"amount"=>"300"},,"2"=>{"amount"=>"300"} }
```

If you want to do this you have to create all of the @obj_products before hand in the `Controller#new` action. That way if there are 3 categories associated, you are passing three Product objects to the form, which will then return a VERY different params hash. Your params hash would have to look like:

```
[{"category_id" => "1", "amount"=>"100"},{"category_id" => "2", "amount"=>"200",...}]
```

But unless you rewrite your controller and form that won't work. You could do:

```
def create
  if FlowBudgetDetail.transaction do
       params["flow_budget_details"].each do |k,v|
         new_record = FlowBudgetDetail.new("category_id" => k, "amount" => v)
         new_record.save
       end
   end
      redirect_to :action=>"index"
   else
     redirect_to :action=>"new"
   end
end
```

OK, this should work verbatim. Don't go changing the Key in `params["flow_budget_details"].each` because that is one reason you are getting the wrong results. Also don't change the order of `.new("category_id" => k, "amount" => v)' because you made it backwards from what I told you last time and that also screwed up your results.

Do exactly this and post the results.

Comment: What error are you getting with `.create`? Any different? I added a loop method alternative.

Comment: I edited all my post and I added my last tried according with your answer is saving...but not correctly.

Comment: Is not exactly the answer that i wanted but helped me to create. Thanks.